# Clips range find between 2 json inputs

Tags: clips

I want to implemen a rule ;

Lets assume that ı have one input.json it consist a name value pair.Example;
{
"quality":"300"
}

I have another constant json ,Example
[{
"up":"100",
"down":"0",
"data":"xx"
},
{
"up":"200",
"down":"100",
"data":"yy"
},
,
{
"up":"300",
"down":"200",
"data":"zz"
}
]

I am trying to find propert value for data for which up and down range.
for this one ı, have to get zz because  "quality":"300" is between 200-300.

how can ı success this one in clips rule.

Comment: if you have time ,please can you look at this  @Gary Riley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate pair
   (slot name)
   (slot value))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts pairs
   (pair (name "quality") (value 300)))
CLIPS>       
(deftemplate data
   (slot name)
   (slot up)
   (slot down))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts data-values
   (data (name "xx") (up 100) (down 0))
   (data (name "yy") (up 200) (down 100))
   (data (name "zz") (up 300) (down 200)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule in-range
   (pair (name "quality")
         (value ?value))
   (data (name ?name)
         (up ?up)
         (down ?down))
   (test (and (> ?value ?down) (<= ?value ?up)))
   =>
   (printout t ?name " is in range." crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (pair (name "quality") (value 300))
f-2     (data (name "xx") (up 100) (down 0))
f-3     (data (name "yy") (up 200) (down 100))
f-4     (data (name "zz") (up 300) (down 200))
For a total of 5 facts.
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      in-range: f-1,f-4
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
zz is in range.
CLIPS>
```